# Error 1064 on MySQL Procedure

Tags: mysql

I create a procedure like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_tambah_na ( IN v_nis VARCHAR( 20 ))
BEGIN
DECLARE v_selesai INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_semester INTEGER;
DECLARE v_nilai INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_jur INTEGER;

DECLARE cur_mp CURSOR FOR 
    select semester, sum(nilai) as jml_nilai_mp from mengambil_mp amp join mata_pelajaran mp on (amp.kd_mp=mp.kd_mp) where nis=v_nis;

SELECT id_jurusan INTO v_jur FROM siswa s jOIN kelas k on (s.id_kelas=k.id_kelas) where nis=v_nis;

DECLARE cur_mp_un CURSOR FOR 
    select semester, sum(nilai) as jml_nilai_mp_un from mengambil_mp amp join mata_pelajaran mp on (amp.kd_mp=mp.kd_mp) where nis=8091010010 and ket_mp_un='ya' and (jurusan=v_jur or jurusan=1) group by semester;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_selesai = 1;

OPEN cur_mp;

get_nilai_mp : LOOP
    FETCH cur_mp INTO v_semester, v_nilai;

    IF v_selesai = 1 THEN
        LEAVE get_nilai_mp;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO nilai_akhir (nis, semester, jml_nilai_mp) VALUES (v_nis, v_semester, v_nilai);
END LOOP get_nilai_mp;
CLOSE cur_mp;

SET v_selesai=0;

OPEN cur_mp_un;

get_nilai_mp_un : LOOP
    FETCH cur_mp_un INTO v_semester, v_nilai;

    IF v_selesai = 1 THEN
        LEAVE get_nilai_mp_un;
    END IF;

    UPDATE nilai_akhir SET nilai=v_nilai WHERE nis=v_nis AND semester=v_semester;

END LOOP get_nilai_mp_un;

CLOSE cur_mp_un;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

but it return an error messege :

> `#`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE cur_mp_un CURSOR FOR select semester, sum(nilai) as jml_nilai_' at line 13

I don't know what is wrong with that line.. I think it's already correct, but why i return that error messege..

PS: sorry for the variable name, I use my native language for them, so don't be bothered by that

Answer (score 0):

There is an aggregated function `sum(nilai)` without the GROUP BY clause.
Aggregated funcions can only be used together with GROUP BY.

> DECLARE cur_mp_un CURSOR FOR
>  
>     select semester, sum(nilai) as jml_nilai_mp
>  
>     from mengambil_mp amp 
>  
>     join mata_pelajaran mp on (amp.kd_mp=mp.kd_mp) 
>  
>         where nis=v_nis
>  
>         **GROUP BY semester ;**